# Forcing HTTPS breaks Admin Pages

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, https

First off, I looked for this and couldn't find it (hence why I am posting). So I apologize if I just missed the solution. I also figured this was a server htaccess issue and not a WordPress issue.

I recently implemented an SSL on my domain. I have corrected all the links in the database and the site works fine as long as I don't force redirect HTTPS. When I do so, it also breaks my WordPress Login page. The login page and admin are both obscured with rewrites just fine. I have copied the important parts of the htaccess file.

```
# Force HTTPS
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Later

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^string1/(.*) /wp-admin/$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^string1(.*) /wp-admin/$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^string2(.*) /wp-login.php$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^string2/(.*) /wp-login.php$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

The first rewrite is at the top of the htaccess file and the second is about midway through. When I don't force the https, a user is still able to access the HTTP version of the site (which defeats the purpose of installing the SSL obviously). When a user is on the HTTP version of the site, because all of the links have been updated, any clicks take the user to the HTTPS version. I assume that the issue is in the {REQUEST_URI} command causing a weird rewrite and consequently ending in a 404. I am not getting any mixed content warnings on the site in Chrome or Firefox.

As a side note, I am not a pro, so please keep it a little basic for me. Thanks. :)

Comment: Are you using your own site cert; or Is SSL instead being provided by a CDN like Cloudflare?

Comment: I purchased an SSL through GoDaddy, my hosting provider. I am not using a CDN at all currently.

Answer (score 0):

I would take off the force HTTPS script from the htaccess and clear the cache do a hard reload. If it still takes you to HTTP version then what i guess is you have mix content. What you can do for this is use this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/better-search-replace/ and replace all "http://" with "https://" . This way it will search for all non https content on the website(including your database) and replace it with https version. After doing that give it some time(10 minutes or so) and try accessing the website again. Let me know if this works

One more thing i wanted to add. If you go to Settings » General , what does your wordpress address url and site address url look like? Make sure they are both running https version.

Regarding my recommendation above, a simpler way to force https without using .htacess function is to use this plugin "Really Simple SSL "